# python requests get aspx issue

Tags: python, python-requests

Please look over my code. What am I doing wrong that my request response is empty? Any pointers?

URL in question: (should generate a results page)

`https://www.ucr.gov/enforcement/343121222`

But I cannot replicate it with python requests. Why?

```
import requests
headers = {'Host': 'www.ucr.gov',
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0',
            'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Connection' : 'keep-alive'

}

data = {
'scheme': 'https;',
'host': 'www.ucr.gov',
'filename': '/enforcement/3431212'
}

url="https://www.ucr.gov/enforcement/3431212"
result = requests.get(url, params=data, headers=headers)

print(result.status_code)
print(result.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page at the link you provided is fully rendered on the client side using JavaScript. This means that you won't be able to obtain the same response using a simple HTTP request.

In this case a common solution is performing something that is called *Headless Scraping*, which involves automating a headless browser in order to access a specific website content as a regular client would. In Python headless scraping can be implemented using several libraries, including [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/).